# Error when executing an INSERT statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to run the following DML statement in a PostgreSQL database:

```
INSERT INTO HMS_RESERVE_CANCEL_DTL
(DIVISION_CODE,         
  UNIT_CODE,            
  RESERVATION_NO,       
  RESERVATION_DATE,     
  CANCELLATION_NO,
  CANCELLATION_DATE,
  CANCELLED_AT_UNIT,
  CANCELLATION_AMOUNT,
  CANCELLED_BY,
  CANCELLATION_REASON,
  REFUND_AMOUNT,
  POSTED_TO_FAS,
  CANCEL_PER,
  room_type,
  no_of_rooms,
  taxes ) 
values(
  '103',
  '10303',
  'GHA1314HTLRS000157',
  case trim('') when trim('08-05-2013') then null else to_date('08-05-2013','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') end,
  'GHA1314HTLCL000002',
  current_date,
  '10303',
  5200.0,
  '001721',
  'my parsanal',
  '53260.00',
  'N',
  10.0,
  '02',
  '10',
  '10320.0')
```

The above statement starts but fails soon after with the following error message:

```
ERROR: numeric field overflow
SQL state: 22003
Detail: The absolute value is greater than or equal to 10^4 for field with precision 6, scale 2.
```

Please help me get rid of this error (or at least point me in the right direction). The table structure for my table (`hms_rserve_cancel_dtl`) is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE hms_reserve_cancel_dtl
(
  division_code character varying(3) NOT NULL,
  unit_code character varying(5) NOT NULL,
  reservation_no character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  reservation_date date NOT NULL,
  cancellation_no character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  cancellation_date date NOT NULL,
  cancelled_at_unit character varying(15) NOT NULL,
  cancellation_amount numeric(7,2),
  cancelled_by character varying(35),
  cancellation_reason character varying(200),
  refund_amount numeric(7,2),
  posted_to_fas character(1) DEFAULT 'N'::bpchar,
  posted_date date,
  remarks character varying(200),
  status character(1) DEFAULT 'A'::bpchar,
  cancel_per numeric(7,2),
  room_type character varying(2),
  no_of_rooms character varying(2),
  refund_status character(1),
  refunded_date date,
  taxes numeric(6,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  CONSTRAINT hms_reserve_cancel_dtl_div_unit_code_fkey FOREIGN KEY (division_code, unit_code)
      REFERENCES aptdc_units_mst (division_code, unit_code) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT hms_reserve_cancel_dtl_reservation_no_fkey FOREIGN KEY (reservation_no, room_type)
      REFERENCES hms_reservation_mst (reservation_no, room_type) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
) 
WITHOUT OIDS;
ALTER TABLE hms_reserve_cancel_dtl OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE hms_reserve_cancel_dtl TO postgres;
```

Comment: What do you think this ("The absolute value is greater than or equal to 10^4 for field with precision 6, scale 2") means? What would happen if you tried to insert 10 people into a smart? Exactly, a CarOverflowException!

Comment: Not trying to be snide, but at a glance I think the schema needs more help than the insert query does.

Answer (score 2):

Your taxes field is designed as numeric(6, 2) which means a total of 6 digits. 4 before the decimal point and 2 behind. The value you supply has 5 digits before the decimal point so it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

[PostgreSQL Docs:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC)

The scale of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point. The precision of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point. So the number 23.5141 has a precision of 6 and a scale of 4.

For example `10123.435` won't fit in `numeric(4,2)`

```
create table tmp (
   a numeric (8,5)
   );

/* ok */ insert into tmp values (123.12345); 
/* ok */ insert into tmp values (1.1); 
-- this will result in 1.12346, because precicion is set to 5!
insert into tmp values (1.123456); 

/* owerflow */ insert into tmp values (1000); 
-- because of number gets rounded to 5 decimal numbers:
/* owerflow */ insert into tmp values (999.99999999999999999999);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined taxes to be maximum 6 digits, where 2 are in the fraction part meaning that 9999.99 is the largest value you may insert. In your insert you try to insert 10320.0 which is too large for this column.

Comment: @DilipReddy please make sure to [accept one of the right answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235). You should do that for all the questions you've asked (where you have got an acceptable answer).